# How to limit db_update() to update first n rows

Tags: 7, database

I want to update first n rows using db_update(). Is it possible?

I know we can use db_query(). something like

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <field_name> = <value> LIMIT <num_rows>
```

I want to know whether this is possible using db_update()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's possible I'm afraid.

[`db_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7) uses the [`UpdateQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/class/UpdateQuery/7) class, which doesn't support the `range()` method that a [`SelectQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) does.

You could probably subclass `UpdateQuery` and add that behaviour, but for the amount of work that would take you might be better off just using a raw SQL statement with `db_query()` like you've suggested.